# Clojure reference Project up to date?

Tags: clojure, lisp

Starting with Clojure I discovered a talk by Rich Hickey where he demonstrates some of Clojure's strengths on a basic [Ant-Simulator](https://github.com/krukow/ants-demo).

Can this code still be considered as a good reference for Clojure? Especially the parts when he recursively sends off functions to agents to simulate a game loop.
Example:

```
(defn animation [x]
  (when b/running
    (send-off *agent* #'animation))
    (. panel (repaint))
  (. Thread (sleep defs/animation-sleep-ms))
  nil)
```

**Edit:**

I am not interested in the `#'` reader macro but more wether it is idiomatic/good Clojure to
recursively call a function on a agent or not.

Comment: What specific code snipped can you post so a problem can be stated, so we can help you? Otherwise, I'm thinking this question belongs over on Programmers.

Comment: Why is the `#' ` reader macro needed when recursively sending `animation` to  `*agent*`?

Comment: This evaluates `animation` every time it is used. This way `animation`can be changed on the fly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This snippet is current in Clojure 1.4. Is it idiomatic for a function to submit a task back to the agent that called it? Yes.

Here is an example that uses a similar approach to recursively calculate a factorial:

```
(defn fac [n limit total]
  (if (< n limit)
    (let [next-n (inc n)]
       (send-off *agent* fac limit (* total next-n)) 
       next-n)
     total))

 (def a (agent 1))

 (await (send-off a fac 5 1))
 ; => nil
 @a
 ;=> 120
```

**Update**

The above is a contrived example and actually not a good one, as there is a race condition between the various recursive `send-off` calls and the later `await`.  There may be some `send-off` calls yet to be added to the agent's task queue.

I re-wrote the above as follows:

```
(defn factorial-using-agent-recursive [x]
  (let [a (agent 1)]
    (letfn [(calc  [n limit total]
               (if (< n limit)
                 (let [next-n (inc n)]
                   (send-off *agent* calc limit (* total next-n))
                   next-n)
                 total))]
      (await (send-off a calc x 1)))
    @a))
```

and observed the following behavior:

```
user=> (for [x (range 10)] (factorial-using-agent-recursive 5))
(2 4 3 120 2 120 120 120 120 2)
user=> (for [x (range 10)] (factorial-using-agent-recursive 5))
(2 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 120 2)
user=> (for [x (range 10)] (factorial-using-agent-recursive 5))
(120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120)
```

Moral of the story is: don't use agents for synchronous calculations. Use them for asynchronous independent tasks - like updating animations displayed to a user :)