# What does "#'symbol" notation mean in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm learning clojure on Heroku using [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clojure-web-application) tutorial. I've come across the same thing in other tutorials, as well.

Anyway, using the jetty adapter in ring, you have something like this:

```
(defroutes routes 
  ...)

(defn start []
  (ring/run-jetty #'routes {:port 8080 :join? false}))
```

I don't understand what `#'routes` means. If I replace it with just `routes` it seems to work fine. What does the `#'symbol` notation mean? It's been very difficult to research.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's a [reader macro](http://clojure.org/reader). `#'foo` expands to `(var foo)`. See [Is pound-quote (hash-quote, #') in Clojure running the resolve and symbol functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945187/is-pound-quote-in-clojure-running-the-resolve-and-symbol-functions), [Difference between Symbols and Vars in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113387/explanation-about-symbols-and-vars-and-their-differences-in-clojure) and http://clojure.org/vars where you can find in-depth discussion.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248754/clojure-reference-project-up-to-date#comment16423142_12248754